# React - How to show an element while hiding the others in React-Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PlanetInfoCard from "./PlanetInfoCard";

interface PlanetInfosProps {
  planetName: string;
  averageTemperature: string;
  distanceFromSun?: string;
  radius: string;
  svg: string;
  isDisplayed: boolean;
}

const PlanetInfos: React.FC<PlanetInfosProps> = ({
  planetName,
  svg,
  distanceFromSun,
  averageTemperature,
  radius,
  isDisplayed,
}) => {
  const [displayStatus, setDisplayStatus] = useState(isDisplayed);

  const displayPlanetInfo = () => {
    setDisplayStatus(!displayStatus);
  };

  return (
    <div
      onClick={displayPlanetInfo}
      key={planetName}
      className="planet-list__infos"
    >
      <li>
        <img src={svg} alt="planet-logo" /> <p>{planetName}</p>
      </li>
      {displayStatus && (
        <PlanetInfoCard
          key={distanceFromSun}
          planetName={planetName}
          svg={svg}
          distanceFromSun={distanceFromSun}
          averageTemperature={averageTemperature}
          radius={radius}
          isDisplayed={isDisplayed}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlanetInfos;
```

In here each planet has isDisplayed value in their data object. I managed to display them individually, using `useState`. But I wanna hide other elements while showing one. I tried to create other states and it got messy, couldn't manage to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a state for deciding which element to show.

like:
`[displayingItem, setDisplayingItem] = useState(oneOfThePlanetNames);`

and you could display any planet you want by `setDisplayinItem(planetName)`

This way only one item displays each time.

```
{displayingItem === planetName && (
        <PlanetInfoCard
          key={distanceFromSun}
          planetName={planetName}
          svg={svg}
          distanceFromSun={distanceFromSun}
          averageTemperature={averageTemperature}
          radius={radius}
          isDisplayed={isDisplayed}
        />
      )}
```

Comment: where is the click event here? I have no idea what is this actually. what is oneOfThePlanetNames? How can that be a state?

Comment: @İlker one of the planet names like 'earth', basically PlanetName of the  PlanetInfoCard that you want to be displayed by default.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in the parent component where your list of PlanetInfos located.

```
   [displayedPlanet, setDisplayedPlanet] = useState('');
   const setPlanet = (name: string) => {setDisplayedPlanet(name)}

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      {listOfPlanets.map((planet) => 
      <div onClick={setPlanet.bind(null, planet.planetName)}>
      {planet.planetName === displayedPlanet && <PlanetInfos planet=planet/>}</div>)}
     </React.Fragment>
)
```

Comment: Ok, the goal is the keep only one planetInfo as a selected, so for that, we have the displayedPlanet state, now onClick you just update this state, and when you're rendering your plaentInfo list you just check if the current state equal to your planetInfo name from the list and if it is you render it with PlanetInfos component